# Appropriate number of explanatory variables in redundancy analysis (RDA)

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, predictor

This question comes from a reviewer's comment on a manuscript I recently submitted. I analyzed a multivariate data set (6 response variables, 21 observations for each) using redundancy analysis (RDA) in `R` with the `vegan` package. I wanted to determine which explanatory variables could best explain the variation of my 6 response variables taken together.

After removing highly correlated (>0.85) explanatory variables, I still had 25 possible explanatory variables for 21 multivariate observations.

I then standardized my response and explanatory variables and ran the following codes:

```
rdax.r <- rda(std_flx~., data=std.div.rda.r)
rday.r <- rda(std_flx~1, data=std.div.rda.r)
rdax_select.r <-ordistep(rdax.r, scope=formula(rday.r), direction="both", Pin = 0.05, Pout = 0.1, perm.max = 9999)
```

The idea here is to use `ordistep` to sequentially test and remove non-significant explanatory variables.

My final model kept 9 explanatory variables that best explained the variation of my 21 multivariate observations.

**My questions: 1) is it appropriate to do this since my full model has 25 explanatory variables but only 21 observations? 2) Is the ratio of explanatory to response variable is too high?**

My understanding is that it’s ok since `ordistep` is sequentially testing the significance of each term and dropping the non-significant ones. Moreover, this technique is similar to the DistLM analysis using the software `PRIMER` with a stepwise procedure based on AICc, but I my case, I'm basing my selection procedure on p-values.

Comment: Alternatively, could you suggest someone that might be able to help me answer this important question?

Comment: What was the reviewer's comment?

Comment: @Maddenker The reviewer's comment was that the number of explanatory variables was high compared to the number of observations, which tend to increase R2 values.

Comment: However, in my case I'm testing (and selecting) which explanatory variables are significantly explaining my 6 response variable variation.

Comment: So you had a total of 126 observations?  Maybe the reviewer didn't understand that.  It is still a low number of observations, enough to be concerned with.

Comment: No, I really have 21 observations. The reason is that I measured 6 chemicals compounds from 21 sediment core incubations. So my response is multivariate (6 response variables) taken from 21 observations (i.e. incubations) and I wanted to find the explanatory variables (25 different diversity indices) which best explained my 6 chemical compounds. I used RDA because I have 6 response variables and used `ordistep` to select the best explanatory variables based on p-values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you use LASSO or Ridge regression, which is meant to handle collinear variables as well as situations with $n<p$ (number of observations less than number of predictors). These occur often in biological data. Tibshirani is one of the pioneers of LASSO regression which is a more proficient regression tool that Ridge regression. What it does is actually determines using cross-validation the most appropriate variables based on your explanatory variables. The beauty of it is that it coerces insignificant variables to 0 through its penalization procedure. Here is a link to guide you on the applications side: https://web.stanford.edu/~vcs/talks/MicrosoftMay082008.pdf.

To run LASSO, use the `glmnet` package in R. It actually has all your diagnostic tools and is simple to use. Here is the link to guide you through the `glmnet` package: http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html. Step AICc, BIC, etc. are used as a "poor man's method" for regression. Often times in the presence of collinear data, the stepwise procedure overshoots the true value of $R^2$. Also the tests used to decide to include a variable or exclude a variable are biased since they are based on the same data (talking about measuring both the testing data and the training data during a validation procedure). Also, from a methods standpoint, people tend not to think about how, why, or when a variable is or is not included in the model: they tend to accept it as is and run with it.

Comment: I have to admit that beside few questions on CV, I wasn't aware of LASSO and Ridge regression, this opens new possibilities that I have to explore. However, before my RDA, I removed collinear explanatory variables and ran the `vif` multicollinearity test, and VIF values are all < 5, so this shouldn't be an issue with my analysis. I'm also aware how variables are included or excluded from RDA, I discuss each one included in the final results and they all make biological sense. So my question remains, is there something fundamentally bad in the analysis I performed?

Comment: I needed more space to add "even if better options may exist"

Comment: @Mud Warrior It is questionable to use stepwise regression for the reasons I discussed. The questions you have to ask yourself are "Why are these variables included or excluded? Why did we consider these variables in the first place?" Basically stepwise inclusion/exclusion negates asking these questions and relegates you to just accept the model as is without question. So you can use AICc as your method as long as you scrutinize your model and think critically of the implications of including and excluding some variables and not others, but LASSO and Ridge are better methods.

Comment: Keeping in mind that Lasso and Ridge are better methods than RDA. If someone go into the full analysis of the RDA model obtained through stepwise selection (which I did), you're saying that this method is not the best but still appropriate if you're # of observations is less than you're # of predictors, right? Do you have a reference for this? I went through Legendre & Legendre (2012) Numerical Ecology, 3rd edition, and although they suggest it, it is not clearly stated.

Comment: @MudWarrior Here is a link to the lecture slides from professor Joseph Cavanaugh of University of Iowa. He has a lot of background in this area and his slides are my go-to reference when I am stuck. http://myweb.uiowa.edu/cavaaugh/ms_lec_3_ho.pdf This is also now available on wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the slides, they should become handy down the road. However, in the case of `ordistep`, the selection criteria is the p-value and AIC is only used as selection criteria in the case where variables have the same p-values.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort you spent on my question. The answer isn't exactly what I was looking for so I won't mark it as accepted for now. However, you definitely deserve the bounty for pointing towards other analyses and explaining your points well. Good job!

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between RDA and the Lasso; RDA allows for multivariate responses whilst the Lasso (in all the implementations I have seen of the original Lasso penalty) is for a univariate response. I would look at `ordiR2step()`, although you will need to drop some of the covariates as it needs to fit the full model and that isn't possible with 21 samples. You might do this by fitting all single term models and drop any variables that are not significant.If that gets you below 21 covariates, then use `ordiR2step()`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could try sparse Redundancy Analysis (incorporates the ridge, lasso, and the elastic net penalization), which helps you to select the optimal number of explanatory variables through penalization and cross validation.

You can find more details in the followin article:

Attila Csala, Frans P J M Voorbraak, Aeilko H Zwinderman, Michel H Hof, Sparse redundancy analysis of high-dimensional genetic and genomic data, Bioinformatics, Volume 33, Issue 20, 15 October 2017, Pages 3228–3234, https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btx374